# Finding Resque Scheduler Jobs Programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

In Rails, you can easily get at the basic info of workers, jobs pending, etc. via `Resque.info` hash. How can you determine how many jobs are in the Resque Scheduler Delayed Jobs (one-off scheduled) tab programmatically?

For example, I see 0 pending jobs in Resque.info but can see 5 jobs under the Delayed tab in Resque Web view. How could I return that 5 (total count or objects)?

Answer (score 0):

For those that may need this in the future, I looked more deeply into how the server page displayed it, and found it uses the method:

`Resque.delayed_queue_peek`, e.g. `Resque.delayed_queue_peek(1, 20)`

Internals available here: https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/blob/master/lib/resque/scheduler/delaying_extensions.rb